$f$ entire, and $g$ is a holomorphic in the punctured disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z|<1\}$, with $f\circ g$ a simple pole at the origin
Suppose that $f$ is an entire function, and $g$ is a holomorphic function in the punctured disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z|<1\}$. If the composite function $f \circ g$ has a simple pole at the origin, then what we deduce about the functions $f$ and $g ?$
If $f(g(z))$ has a simple pole at the origin, as $f$ is entire, $g$ must have a pole at the origin, and since the pole is simple, $f$ must be a polynomial, or else $f\circ g$ would have an essential singularity at the origin. In fact, $f$ must have degree 1, since otherwise, the pole at the origin would at least be of order $2$. The pole of $g$ must be simple, thus $1/g(z)=z h(z)$, where $h$ is analytic and $h(0)\neq 0$. Thus, $g(z)=\frac{h_1(z)}{z}$, with $h_1=1/h$ analytic.
Is this correct? I am aware that this question has been asked before, but I believe my proof is slightly different and does not compute $(zf(g(z))'$.

You use the fact that "$f$ must be a polynomial......." directly（without proof）, this fact is not obviously. And the old post , it proves that $f'$ is constant and then $f$ is linear! Also, you use the fact that $g$ has  a simple pole at the origin. Both of these should be proved!

I explain clearly why I believe $f$ should be a polynomial. As to why $g$ is simple, any higher order pole would lead to a pole of $f\circ g$ of order $2$ or more.

Your so-called "Proof" is "$f$ must be a polynomial, or else $f\circ g$ would have an essential singularity at the origin." But this is not obviously.

Anyway, if you think it is a proof , it is OK now!

Also it is no need to open a new post for the same question. You can post your answer in that post, then someone can see your proof there and give you a updovote! This is my personal advice.

On top of the conclusion that @Riemann points out as having no back-up argument, it's also not immediately obvious (although true) that $g$ cannot have an essential singularity at $0$.
